# Issue with GLIBC Version on CentOS Running on Windows

Tags: deployment, server, centos, centos7, hetzner-cloud

I'm encountering compatibility issues with GLIBC on CentOS, running on Windows. The error messages suggest a mismatch in GLIBC versions. I run the command 'npm run build' to build the project but encountering this issue:
[image: Problem's SS]

I've tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

1. changed the node version to 14,15,16,20
2. uninstalled and reinstalled dependencies(the node v20.10.0 can't even install deps & return the same error as in picture)
3. I searched on internet but did not any relevant issue like this.

How can I fix this issue? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

May the following details help:

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```